# How to create an array in shell script for the following json output?

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, amazon-ecs

I am new to shell scripting, however i was trying to parse a command output and store those id values as an array.,

```
C:\Users\Shruthi>aws ecs list-tasks --cluster test-cluster --service hello2-service

{
    "taskArns": [
        "arn:aws:ecs:ap-south-1:822063991960:task/6990efe7-4a81-4fe7-8d25-d1ec1898971e",
        "arn:aws:ecs:ap-south-1:822063991960:task/0281508f-4d90-4ebc-afcd-684f58f5405e"
    ]
}
```

i want to store the above taskArns in to a array variable,

```
taskArn = (arn:aws:ecs:ap-south-1:822063991960:task/6990efe7-4a81-4fe7-8d25-d1ec1898971e arn:aws:ecs:ap-south-1:822063991960:task/0281508f-4d90-4ebc-afcd-684f58f5405e ..)
```

and so on, So that i can further use this task id's to describe specific task and find its current status.

---

i implemented the answered method, however i am not able to use the $line variable value for command substitution,

```
echo $FOO | while read -r line; do
    name="$line"
    echo "Name read from file - $name"

    #Successfully describes
    val="arn:aws:ecs:ap-southeast-1:296646925901:task/4d2bf627-82f5-45c7-8ad4-60b9e2f1934a"
    aws ecs describe-tasks --cluster mol-dev-cluster --tasks $val

    #Errors out
    aws ecs describe-tasks --cluster mol-dev-cluster --tasks $line
done
```

results in below error

```
error   14-Nov-2019 11:25:12    An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the DescribeTasks operation: taskId length should be one of [32,36]
simple  14-Nov-2019 11:25:12    Failing task since return code of [/tmp/runInDocker4657237329652069100.sh /home/bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/temp/47349848-46924268-46636883-ScriptBuildTask-5580550432412549027.sh] was 255 while expected 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put the output in `foo.json` for easy access.
You could use `jq` to put those *arns* in a variable like this:

```sh
FOO=$(cat foo.json | jq .taskArns[])                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
-> echo $FOO                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
"arn:aws:ecs:ap-south-1:822063991960:task/6990efe7-4a81-4fe7-8d25-d1ec1898971e"
"arn:aws:ecs:ap-south-1:822063991960:task/0281508f-4d90-4ebc-afcd-684f58f5405e"
```

Now you can simply iterate that variable:

```
echo $FOO | while read line                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
do
 echo $line
done
```